# neo4j: massive speed difference for queries in unix console vs. web browser

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j, I've noticed for simple queries the UNIX console is way faster than the web browser.  For my locally-hosted db of ~3000 nodes, typical queries take well under 1s in the console, but over 5s on my browser even when returning only a single item displayed as text (no node rendering).  This makes using the built-in graph visualizer less than ideal for research purposes.  Is there a visualizer that can plug into neo4j and get sub 1s performance on simple queries?  And why is the web browser so slow for these basic queries?  I'm using google chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit), neo4j 3.2.0 community edition on Mac OS El capitan.

Comment: I've noticed that with an embedded database, the second and subsequent runs of the same query (even with different parameters) show a 10-100x performance increase.  Just a guess, but maybe the browser interface doesn't benefit from query and/or entity caching.

Comment: Did you configure the browser interface to use Bolt? Also: Remember the browser interface is likely not optimized for performance, as a native database call would be.

Comment: using localhost:7474 ? Same with you IP ?